# Add trailing number of zeros based on the number count of leading numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to know how can I add trailing zeros based on the number count in JavaScript
Ex- number 17.23, 
I am splitting the number based on decimal
So a[0]=17 and a[1]=23.
Now i want to divide 23 by 100 ie (23 means two digits ) divided by (1 + zero will be the number of digits in numerator)
these numbers will be dynamic so will the number of zeros too. Next if i have 678.8996 so now the answer should be 8996/10000

Comment: the trailing zeros for a precise known number of decimals n can be added with .toFixed(n)` function. Apart from that, keep in mind that if you are storing your numbers as a `number` type, you could be surprised of the fact, for instance, 678.8996 will not be stored as *exactly* 678.8996. Even if they are stored as a string, your description is pretty unclear to me.

Comment: `a[1] = +('0.' + a[1])`

Comment: Are you just trying to get rid of the integral part of a decimal number? `y = x - Math.trunc(x)`

Comment: Do you have a code attempt, where you can point out how it's not working exactly with an exemple input ? I'm trying to understand what would be the *input* and the corresponding *output* in general. By reading your example, I'm still confused.

Comment: what if the number is 8.0012 - how do you store the "12", as 12? or "0012" ... it's important, because if you store it as 12, then you'll be pushing uphill trying to get code to do what you want

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen that won't necessarily work because of FP precision - `console.log(17.23-Math.floor(17.23))` => `0.23000000000000043`

Comment: @Nick All true, but to be honest, I still have no idea what the actual question is...

Answer (score 0):

If all you are wanting to do is get a "1 + a dynamic amount of zeros", then you are really just dealing with powers of 10, which would be 10 to the power of the length of your numerator. So you can use the `Math.pow()` function to get your dynamic power of ten. I am not sure if you are storing integers or strings in your array, so I am going to assuming you are storing strings.

Here is an example if you were storing strings in the array:

```
var answer = parseInt(a[1]) / Math.pow(10, a[1].length);
```